# List users from two tables

Tags: mysql, join, ascii

Hi i have `user_table1` and `user_table2` also i have table `jobs` and `employers`

My request works when i get users from user_table1 and pull jobs and employers info for them, but when i join user table2 its only doubles output from user_table1 rather than showing users from second table.

```
SELECT user_table1.age, user_table1.name,  user_table1.lname, jobs.position, jobs.wage, employers.name employers.phone 
from user_table1 
LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.position_id = user_table1.position_id
LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.position_id = jobs.position_id 
WHERE user_table1.age < 30
ORDER BY user_table1.age ASC
```

Now i also tried  to add

```
SELECT user_table1.age, user_table1.name,  user_table1.lname, jobs.position, jobs.wage, employers.name employers.phone 
from user_table1 
LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.position_id = user_table1.position_id
LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.position_id = jobs.position_id 
LEFT JOIN user_table2 ON jobs.position = user_table2.position
WHERE user_table1.age < 30
user_table2.status = 4
ORDER BY user_table1.age ASC
```

On other words i need to check where `user_table2.status=4` and then combine this records with all records from `user_table1` where `age less than 30` and then pull fields from `jobs` and `employers` for this records.

Answer (score 0):

Try UNIONing your two tables. You'll need to specify your `ORDER BY` clause outside the `UNION`. UNION ALL allows duplicates. If you don't want dupes, remove the `ALL` and use `UNION` only.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT u.age, u.name,  u.lname, jobs.position, jobs.wage, employers.name employers.phone 
    from user_table1 as u
    LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.position_id = u.position_id
    LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.position_id = jobs.position_id 
    WHERE u.age < 30

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT u.age, user_table1.name,  user_table1.lname, jobs.position, jobs.wage, employers.name employers.phone 
    from user_table2 u  
    LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.position_id = u.position_id
    LEFT JOIN employers ON employers.position_id = jobs.position_id 
    WHERE u.age < 30
    AND u.status = 4
) AS UU
ORDER BY  UU.Age ASC
```

I wasn't clear on your conditions for user_table1 and user_table2 with respect to whether both should get the age 30 filter, and whether table2 should be the only one with the status 4 filter. Modify as you need.

Comment: looks good but this is not my usual way of writing request. I think i had this problem before and then fixed it but now i cannot find it, 
Is there something SIMPLER to do with my original query to make it work?

Comment: @Johnds: if I can paraphrase your question, let me know if I get it right. Take records from 2 tables, with different filtering conditions, and put all results into one resultset. Is this a correct description of your question?

Comment: @Johnds: you can't get much simpler than a UNION.